# Why is my select not being populated with this Meteor code?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I've got the following code to try to populate a select:

In \lib\mongo.js:

```
JobLocations = new Mongo.Collection("jobLocations");
```

In \server\scheduler.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    if (JobLocations.find().count() == 0) {
      console.log('JobLocations collection empty; inserting');

      JobLocations.insert({ value: "1", display: "Uno" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "2", display: "Dos" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "3", display: "Tres" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "4", display: "Cuatro" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "5", display: "Cinco" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "6", display: "Seis" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "7", display: "Siete" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "8", display: "Ocho" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "9", display: "Nueve" });
      JobLocations.insert({ value: "10", display: "Zehn" });
    }
});

Meteor.publish("jobLocations", function () {
  return JobLocations.find();
});

Meteor.methods({
    'insertJobLocations': function(companyId, jobLoc) {
        JobLocations.insert({
            jl_companyid: companyId,
            jl_jobloc: jobLoc,
            jl_created_by: Meteor.userId()
        });
    }
});
```

In \client\main.js:

```
  Meteor.subscribe("jobLocations");

  Template.tblScheduler.helpers({
    jobLocations: function() {
        return JobLocations.find();
    }
  });
```

In \client\main.html:

```
<select name="date1Shift1JobLoc1Count" id="date1Shift1JobLoc1Count">
    {{#each jobLocations}}
        <option value={{jl_jobloc}}>{{jl_jobloc}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

### UPDATE

After removing all the records from the Collection, I changed the server Startup function in server.js to this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    if (JobLocations.find().count() == 0) {
      console.log('JobLocations collection empty; inserting');

      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Uno" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Dos" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Tres" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Cuatro" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Cinco" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Seis" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Siete" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Ocho" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Nueve" });
      JobLocations.insert({ jl_companyid: "axx", jl_jobloc: "Zehn" });
    }
});
```

...and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What's a `jl_jobloc`? That doesn't appear anywhere in the documents you inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the Meteor Method portion of the scheduler.js, but that smells like you're on the right track (to mix some metaphors).

Comment: But if the method isn't used to insert the documents, then they won't have the aforementioned field. Your startup code doesn't call the method. QED.

Comment: No repro on http://meteorpad.com/pad/SysKmW528RsHT2NrH/Repro

Comment: Sure looks like it works in the meteorpad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
   jobLocations: function() {
        return JobLocations.find().fetch();
    }
```